# Protractor Failed: Error while running testForAngular: Error: Permission denied to access property "invoke"

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I started with this basic protractor tests to check if the menu link works. Whenever I try to run the tests, I get timed out `error.SOmething` like this

> Protractor Message: Failed: Error while running testForAngular: Error: Permission denied to access property "invoke"

The **firefox browser** will open the base URL but it will not click on the menu item link. I followed this [tutorial/blog](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2015/11/09/using-protractor-for-e2e-testing-of-angularjs-application-in-visual-studio/)

I am using angular 2.4.10, "typescript": "2.2.2" and "protractor": "5.1.2"

```
//menu.js
    describe(‘menu check’, function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
    browser.get(‘http://localhost:8080/#/');
    browser.waitForAngular();
    });

    it(‘Should route to the view1page from menu’, function () {
    element(by.linkText('View1')).click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('http://localhost:8080/#/view1');
    });

    it(‘Should route to the view2 page from menu’, function () {
    element(by.linkText('View2')).click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toMatch('http://localhost:8080/#/view2');
    });
    });

//conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['menu.js'],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox',

},
//allScriptsTimeout: 360000, 
// Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true, // Use colors in the command line report.
   //defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000
  }
}

//app.component.ts
menuLinksLeft: Array<Link> = [
    { name: 'View1', url: '#/view1' },
    { name: 'View2', url: '#/view2' }
  ];

//app.component.html
<app-menu [leftLinks]="menuLinksLeft" [rightLinks]="menuLinksRight"></app-menu>

//When launched - In browser element
<a ng-reflect-href="#/view1" href="#/view1">View1</a>
```

Comment: browser.waitForAngular(); comment this line and try

Comment: @SureshSalloju I commented and tried still the same error

Comment: are you able to browse site at `localhost:8080`, I think website is not hosted and its a navigation issue

Comment: @harishr I am able browse the site at localhost:8080 and website is hosted.

Comment: @SureshSalloju No it didn't work. I tried to change the browser to chrome. I get `Google chrome cannot be run as root` and the it wont launch the browser